# Создание API-ключа GoogleMaps для Localhost

Tags: google-maps-api, localhost

Захостил свой веб-сайт на `localhost` и на веб-сайте отображаю карту, где отмечаю две марки и визуализирую кратчайший путь между ними.
Проблема в том, что создал API-ключ по определенному алгоритму и карта работает. НО, там выходит текст "For developers only". Как этого избежать?

До этого я использовал API с самого Google Maps. Тогда такой текст не отображался, но проблема в том, что тот API в случае `localhost` не работает.

Создал ключ по этому алгоритму:

> 1.Go to this address: https://console.developers.google.com/apis
> 2.Create new project and Create Credentials (API key)
> 3.Click on "Library"
> 4.Click on any API that you want
> 5.Click on "Enable"
> 6.Click on "Credentials" > "Edit Key"
> 7.Under "Application restrictions", select "HTTP referrers (web sites)"
> 8.Under "Website restrictions", Click on "ADD AN ITEM"
> 9.Type your website address (or "localhost", "127.0.0.1", "localhost:port" etc for local tests) in   the text field and press ENTER to add it to the list
> 10.SAVE and Use your key in your project

Хостинг сделал через Python:
[image: скриншот выполняющегося Python-сервера]

Comment: Может, нужно указать localhost:8000, раз уж хостинг сделан на порту 8000?